# hiding the scope in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, scope, dotnetnuke

I have a problem in which I need to hide results until the user has started typing into the search bar. I am using a DotNetNuke plugin, and therefore did not build this module myself. The scopes I believe I need to use are for '`.angrid-search`' which has a method that returns the search terms, which it will then use in order to decide if the 'angrid-grid' will be displayed. This is the code I have tried thus far, as well as many different similar variations.

```
if (angular.element($('.angrid-search')).searchTerms === undefined){
    angular.element($('.angrid-grid')).hide();
}
```

`angular.element($('.angrid-search'))` comes back with `undefined`, and returns the search terms once something is typed in. It seems to me that the problem is in the second line, in which I try to hide the element.

I am extremely new to Angular (this is pretty much my first real problem), so explaining in layman's terms would be greatly appreciated, especially since I need to learn just as importantly as I need to solve this problem.

Here is the basic DOM

```
<div class="angrid">
    <div class="angrid-search">
    </div>
    <div class="angrid-grid-view">
        <div class="angrid-grid">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There is a bunch of stuff inbetween, but these are the relavent scopes and I did not want to cpypst the inspector window. My main question is: Is the `.hide()` method supposed to work in this type of sitation?

Comment: I sympathize with your situation, but put yourself in our shoes: *all* we have to go on is your post, which is not nearly enough for us to compose an answer without resorting to guesses and generic bits of advice. Ideally, you'd create an [mcve], or at least something that comes closes (e.g. more code and actual context).

Comment: I edited I hope this is more useful now. Because I don't really know the strategy to do this, it is difficult for me to know what context someone who knows how to do this might need.

Comment: why can't you do it the angular way using `ngHide`? (`ng-hide="!searchTerms || searchTerms == ''"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like.

```
<div class="angrid">
<div class="angrid-search">
</div>
<div class="angrid-grid-view">
    <div class="angrid-grid" ng-hide="hidegrid">
    </div>
</div>
```

and in js

```
if (angular.element($('.angrid-search')).searchTerms === undefined){
    angular.element($('.angrid-grid')).hidegrid = true;
}
```

Comment: Yes thanks I didn't know there was an ng-hide directive. I have had trouble in the past making changes directly to the html files, which is why I wanted to avoid it if possible.

Comment: I see..  But so much simpler, yes :)

Comment: Definitely! I am starting to understand the dynamic of angular. This solidified it a bit more, as I have seen a lot of this type of logic be pushed to the view. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's supposed to work. Here's a demo:

```js
angular.module('demo', [])
  .controller('demoCtrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.testFn = function() {
        if (angular.element($('.angrid-search')).searchTerms === undefined) {
          angular.element($('.angrid-grid')).hide();
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<script data-require="jquery@1.11.3" data-semver="1.11.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="demoCtrl">
  <div class="angrid">
    <div class="angrid-search"></div>
    <div class="angrid-grid-view">
      <div class="angrid-grid">Grid!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button ng-click="testFn()">the code will work...</button>
</div>
```

By the way, you mention:

> `angular.element($('.angrid-search'))` comes back with `undefined`

If it does, then obviously hiding things will not work. You should probably ask another question with enough information to reproduce that problem scenario from scratch, so we can help without resorting to guessing.

Comment: I am confused as to how hiding things wouldn't work if the search terms are undefined? I think I have found enough information to solve the problem with the given information. Thanks!

Comment: Your comment says something subtly but very different from the quoted bit of question. In the comment you mention "**search terms**", but in the question it's "**`angular.element($('.angrid-search'))`**".

Comment: in the question it is "angular.element($('.angrid-search')).searchTerms" which comes back as undefined. The search terms are undefined, as nothing has been typed into the search bar. Once you type into the bar "hello", the search term will return "hello". I would like for the grid to be hidden when the search terms are undefined, because this occurs when nothing's been typed in yet.